# Grothendieck-Messing theory

Tags: deformation-theory, abelian-varieties, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello,

I would like to work out some examples of deformation of isogenies via Grothendieck-Messing theory. Let's take an easy example: Let A be an abelian variety over $k=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ and $f:A\rightarrow A$ be the multiplication by $p$ map. Let 
$M=\mathbb{D}(A)$ be the Dieudonné module of $A$. It is a free $W(k)$-module of rank $2 dim(A)$. Finally let  $R=\frac{k[t]}{(t^2)}$.

Then lifting $A$ to $R$ boils down to lifting the Hodge filtration
$$0 \rightarrow \frac{FM}{pM} \rightarrow \frac{M}{pM} \rightarrow \frac{VM}{pM} \rightarrow 0 $$
to a filtration over $R$:
$$0 \rightarrow P \rightarrow \frac{M}{pM}\otimes R \rightarrow P' \rightarrow 0 $$

Here I have used the fact that what is written sometimes $\mathbb{D}(A)_k$ is actually $\frac{M}{pM}$, and $\mathbb{D}(A)_R=\mathbb{D}(A)_k \otimes R$ (am I right ?). Now, let's move on to deforming the isogeny $f$. Lifting $f$ to $R$ is equivalent to lifting two such Hodge filtrations in a compatible way with $f$. Here is what I don't understand:

The map $f_k$ induced by $f$ on $\mathbb{D}(A)_k=\frac{M}{pM}$ is obviously the zero map. But how can I compute the map induced on $\mathbb{D}(A)_R$ ? Is it simply $f_k\otimes R=0$ ? I doubt it.

Thank you!

Jean-Stefan

Comment: The map induced by $f$ on $\mathbb{D}(A)$ is just multiplication by $p$! Why do you find this so unbelievable?

Comment: Yes, the map induced on $\mathbb{D}(A)$ is multiplication by $p$, but what about the map induced on $\mathbb{D}(A)_R$ ?

Comment: You may use the universal property of tensor product to transfer multiplication by $p$ to the right side.

Comment: By $\mathbb{D}(A)$ I meant the Dieudonne crystal of $A$. 

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand: To an abelian variety over $k=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, we can associate a Dieudonné module $\mathbb{D}(A)$ which is a free $W(k)$-module. Now, according to Grothendick-Messing theory, for every locally nilpotent divided power extension $R/k$, there is also a free $R$-module $\mathbb{D}(A)_R$. What is the connection between $\mathbb{D}(A)$ and $\mathbb{D}(A)_R$ ?

My first thought was that $\mathbb{D}(A)_R=\mathbb{D}(A)\otimes_{W(k)} R$, where $R$ is considered a $W(k)$-module via the map $W(k)\rightarrow k \rightarrow R$. Is this true ?

Comment: I would like to follow up on my previous comment. If indeed $\mathbb{D}(A)_R=\mathbb{D}(A) \otimes_{W(k)}R$, then there is a big problem. Let $f:A\rightarrow A$ be an isogeny which factors by multiplication by $p$: $f=pg$, where $g$ is another isogeny. Lifting $f$ to $R$ is the same as lifting in a compatible way with $f$ two Hodge filtrations. But the map induced by $f$ on $\mathbb{D}(A)_R$ is just the zero map because $f$ factors by $p$. So the compatibility condition disappears completely, and lifting $f$ reduces to lifting two copies of $A$. That looks unreasonable to me.

Comment: Given any isogeny $g:A\to B$, and lifts $\widetilde{A}$ and $\widetilde{B}$ over $R$, $f=pg$ lifts uniquely to a map $\widetilde{f}:\widetilde{A}\to\widetilde{B}$. The main point is that $K=\ker(\widetilde{B}\to B)$ is killed by $p$ (viewed as group schemes over $R$). This is because you can use the divided powers to define a logarithm map $K\into Lie(\widetilde{B})$; see II.2.2 in Messing, The Crystals associated to Barsotti-Tate groups. From this, you can deduce the result from the argument in Lemma 1.1.3 in Katz, Serre-Tate Local Moduli.